# Run my example in code igniter

Tags: php

I have installed wamp and code igniter in Windows. Now instruction says
Usage:

```
$this->load->library('bubble');

            Encode :
            $this->bubble->encode('Pineapple');
```

Where to run this in Windows?

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
    // Original
    Bubble Babble Binary Data Encoding - PHP5 Library

    See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_Babble for details.

    Copyright 2011 BohwaZ - http://bohwaz.net/

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

    // For CodeIgniter
    Bubble Babble for CodeIgniter, by Akira : http://www.akibatech.fr
    Licence : WTFPL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL)

    Using with CodeIgniter :

        Copy Bubble.php in your library folder.

        Then, you need to load this library in CodeIgniter :
        $this->load->library('bubble');

        Encode :
        $this->bubble->encode('Pineapple');
        // => xigak-nyryk-humil-bosek-sonax

        Decode :
        $this->bubble->decode('xigak-nyryk-humil-bosek-sonax');
        // => Pineapple

        Detect BubbleBabble's encoding :
        $this->bubble->detect($string);
        // => true of false
*/

class Bubble 
{
    protected $vowels = 'aeiouy';
    protected $consonants = 'bcdfghklmnprstvzx';

    public function encode($src)
    {
        $src = (string) $src;
        $out = 'x';
        $c = 1;

        for ($i = 0;; $i += 2)
        {
            if ($i >= strlen($src))
            {
                $out .= $this->vowels[$c%6] . $this->consonants[16] . $this->vowels[$c/6];
                break;
            }

            $byte1 = ord($src[$i]);

            $out .= $this->vowels[((($byte1>>6)&3)+$c)%6];
            $out .= $this->consonants[($byte1>>2)&15];
            $out .= $this->vowels[(($byte1&3)+($c/6))%6];

            if ($i+1 >= strlen($src))
                break;

            $byte2 = ord($src[$i + 1]);
            $out .= $this->consonants[($byte2>>4)&15];
            $out .= '-';
            $out .= $this->consonants[$byte2&15];

            $c = ($c * 5 + $byte1 * 7 + $byte2) % 36;
        }

        $out .= 'x';
        return $out;
    }

    protected function _decode2WayByte($a1, $a2, $offset)
    {
        if ($a1 > 16)
            show_error("Corrupt string at offset ".$offset);

        if ($a2 > 16)
            show_error("Corrupt string at offset ".($offset+2));

        return ($a1 << 4) | $a2;
    }

    protected function _decode3WayByte($a1, $a2, $a3, $offset, $c)
    {
        $high2 = ($a1 - ($c%6) + 6) % 6;

        if ($high2 >= 4)
            show_error("Corrupt string at offset ".$offset);

        if ($a2 > 16)
            show_error("Corrupt string at offset ".($offset+1));

        $mid4 = $a2;
        $low2 = ($a3 - ($c/6%6) + 6) % 6;

        if ($low2 >= 4)
            show_error("Corrupt string at offset ".($offset+2));

        return $high2<<6 | $mid4<<2 | $low2;
    }

    protected function _decodeTuple($src, $pos)
    {
        $tuple = array(
            strpos($this->vowels, $src[0]),
            strpos($this->consonants, $src[1]),
            strpos($this->vowels, $src[2])
        );

        if (isset($src[3]))
        {
            $tuple[] = strpos($this->consonants, $src[3]);
            $tuple[] = '-';
            $tuple[] = strpos($this->consonants, $src[5]);
        }

        return $tuple;
    }

    public function decode($src)
    {
        $src = (string) $src;

        $c = 1;

        if ($src[0] != 'x')
            show_error("Corrupt string at offset 0: must begin with a 'x'");

        if (substr($src, -1) != 'x')
            show_error("Corrupt string at offset 0: must end with a 'x'");

        if (strlen($src) != 5 && strlen($src)%6 != 5)
            show_error("Corrupt string at offset 0: wrong length");

        $src = str_split(substr($src, 1, -1), 6);
        $last_tuple = count($src) - 1;
        $out = '';

        foreach ($src as $k=>$tuple)
        {
            $pos = $k * 6;
            $tuple = $this->_decodeTuple($tuple, $pos);

            if ($k == $last_tuple)
            {
                if ($tuple[1] == 16)
                {
                    if ($tuple[0] != $c % 6)
                        show_error("Corrupt string at offset $pos (checksum)");
                    if ($tuple[2] != (int)($c / 6))
                        show_error("Corrupt string at offset ".($pos+2)." (checksum)");
                }
                else
                {
                    $byte = $this->_decode3WayByte($tuple[0], $tuple[1], $tuple[2], $pos, $c);
                    $out .= chr($byte);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $byte1 = $this->_decode3WayByte($tuple[0], $tuple[1], $tuple[2], $pos, $c);
                $byte2 = $this->_decode2WayByte($tuple[3], $tuple[5], $pos);

                $out .= chr($byte1);
                $out .= chr($byte2);

                $c = ($c * 5 + $byte1 * 7 + $byte2) % 36;
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }

    public function detect($string)
    {
        if ($string[0] != 'x' || substr($string, -1) != 'x')
            return false;

        if (strlen($string) != 5 && strlen($string)%6 != 5)
            return false;

        if (!preg_match('/^(['.$this->consonants.$this->vowels.']{5})(-(?1))*$/', $string))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Run it from your www directory? Navigate to where you installed WAMP, find the ww folder and place both files in there. Then open a browser and type in localhost/yourFileName.php and it should display.

Comment: Can you please help me this is first time I am using this.I wanted to decode some string in cryptography ony php was available so trying this in command line i am trying to  do this->load->library('bubble');
 It doesnt work

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to help, but not totally sure I understand your question at the moment.

Comment: If you check usage part I am not aware how they are calling

Comment: I dont understand  $this->load->library('bubble'); what this means I shld run this from where?

Comment: http://localhost/bubble.php gives http://localhost/bubble.php            No direct script access allowed

Comment: I have copied bubble.php in library folder of codeigniter

Comment: PHP is mainly built for use on the web, frameworks like CodeIgniter even more so. If you're trying to run this on the command line, you're probably heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: I have 2 functions encode and decode  I have placed in www folder as Bubble.php how to use them